# How to extract info from the dictionaries within a list?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, extract

I'm new to Python, trying to gather data from a json file that consists of a list that contains info inside dictionaries as follows. How do I extract the "count" data from this? (Without using list comprehension)

```
{
   "stats":[
      {
        "name":"Ron",
        "count":98
      },
      {
        "name":"Sandy",
        "count":89
      },
      {
        "name":"Sam",
        "count":77
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Please post the expected output

Comment: Why don't you use simple `for` loop?

Comment: "*Without using list comprehension*", why?

Answer (score 0):

Index the list using the `stats` key then iterate through it

```
data = {
   "stats":[
      {
        "name":"Ron",
        "count":98
      },
      {
        "name":"Sandy",
        "count":89
      },
      {
        "name":"Sam",
        "count":77
      }
   ]
}
for stat in data['stats']:
    count = stat['count']
```

Comment: Hmm isn't that just going to tell us how many dictionaries are within 'stats'? I want to collect the numerical values from "count" to do calculations

Answer (score 0):

Consider the dictionary data stored in a variable source.

```
    source = {
   "stats":[
      {
        "name":"Ron",
        "count":98
      },
      {
        "name":"Sandy",
        "count":89
      },
      {
        "name":"Sam",
        "count":77
      }
   ]
}
```

Now to access the count field inside of "stats" we use indexing.
For example, to view the count of "Ron" you would write:

```
print(source['stats'][0]['count'])
```

This will result in **98**

Similarly, for "Sam" it will be

```
print(source['stats'][2]['count'])
```

And the result will be **77**

In short, we first index the key of dictionary, then the array position and then provide the filed from array of which you want the data.
I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `append` all those values to do calculations:

```
count_values = []

for dic in data['stats']:
    count_values.append(dic['count'])

# Do anything with count_values
print(count_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), "Simple is better than complex."

Thus, list comprehension is actually the best way to extract the information you need and still have it available for further processing (in the form of a list of count values).

```
d = <your dict-list>
count_data_list = [ x['count'] for x in d['stats'] ]
```

If not, and your intention is to process the "count" data as it is extracted, I'd suggest a for-loop:

```
d = <your dict-list>
for x in d['stats']:
  count_data = x['count']
  <process "count_data">
```

Answer (score 0):

using a `map` function will do that in a single line

```
>>> result = list(map(lambda x: x['count'], data['stats']))
[98, 89, 77]
```